# Installation error - Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl

Tags: node.js, ssl, curl, npm

I tried to install `node-parquet` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-parquet) on RHEL EC2 with following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/mvertes/node-parquet.git
cd node-parquet
git submodule update --init --recursive
npm install
```

and getting error:

```
--- LOG END ---
         error: downloading 'https://github.com/apache/arrow/archive/0e21f84c2fc26dba949a03ee7d7ebfade0a65b81.tar.gz' failed
         status_code: 1
         status_string: "Unsupported protocol"
         log:
         --- LOG BEGIN ---
         Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl
```

I tried:

```
wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.64.0.tar.gz
tar -xzf curl-7.64.0.tar.gz
cd curl-7.64.0
./configure --with-ssl 
make 
make install # (if not root, use sudo before command)
```

and installation seems to be fine but same issue (same error) showed up.

Do I need to uninstall current CURL first or what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Probably npm is still using the first version of curl. Two options

- Uninstall the first curl
- Set the PATH variable to choose the second version

Comment: Do you have maybe example?

Comment: Try ``/usr/bin/curl  https://github.com/apache/arrow/archive/0e21f84c2fc26dba949a03ee7d7ebfade0a65b81.tar.gz`` if not working try ``/usr/local/bin/curl https://github.com/apache/arrow/archive/0e21f84c2fc26dba949a03ee7d7ebfade0a65b81.tar.gz`` to see which version is causing the problem